# why lscpu CPU MHz != dmidecode Current Speed

Tags: rhel

In the example below i try to obtain my CPU (Xeon E5-2690 v3) current speed using two different commands, but they report different values - 2.6 Ghz and 3.1 GHz:

```
[root@localhost]# lscpu | grep MHz
CPU MHz:               3099.992
[root@localhost]# dmidecode -t processor | grep Speed
        Max Speed: 4000 MHz
        Current Speed: 2600 MHz
```

Why these values are different? What is the speed of my CPU 2.6 or 3.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dmidecode reads the values from the ACPI tables (which are part of BIOS). The ACPI tables are not always correct, at least according to the dmidecode man pages. Lscpu probably reads the value from sysfs which gets the number from the CPU.

Comment: thanks, I'm not sure if it make sense to create command that produce "not always correct" results. According to your answer `dmidecode` part that displays "Current Speed" is useless because it produce wrong result.

Comment: What he means is that `dmidecode` asks the BIOS - that's it's purpose.  If the BIOS provides false information, dmidecode has no way of telling.

Comment: Yes, it is like that. The purpose of the ACPI tables is to give enough information to the OS so it can initialize the system. If some of this information is incorrect, no one will usually notice  . Dmidecode is useful for debugging in case the OS cannot figure out something correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Your CPU has a rated speed of **4000 MHz**, as shown by `dmidecode`. At the time you checked using `lscpu`, it was running at **3099 MHz**.

When load is low, the CPU runs at a lower speed to save energy and keep itself cooler.

Comment: these commands executed at the same time so I expect cpu speed to match. it doesn't matter how many times I repeat this test - I always have same results. (actually I expect my CPU to be "forced" to run at 3.1 so I wonder why I have 2.6 at one of the commands)